# Doctrine is not flushing entity and is returning the wrong value, what's happen?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.7

I have this piece of code as part of a Restful API method:

```
// $soqlObj1['records'][0]['Id'] == "005800000039cQbAAI"

$entRep = $em->getRepository('PDOneBundle:Representative')->find($soqlObj1['records'][0]['Id']);

dump($entRep); // line 114

if ($entRep->getRepTokenId() === null) {
    $xsession = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(100));
    $entRep->setRepTokenId($xsession);
    $em->flush();

    dump($xsession); // line 121
    dump($entRep->getRepTokenId()); // line 122
}

dump($entRep); // line 125
```

This are the outputs from each `dump()` statement:

```
in SessionRestController.php line 114:

Representative {#2369 ▼
  #rep_id: "005800000039cQbAAI"
  #display_name: "Joan Brooks"
  #avatar_url: "https://pdone.s3.amazonaws.com/avatar/default_avatar.png"
  #rep_type: "VEEVA"
  #username: "ertvn52@pdi-inc.com.train"
  #first: "Joan"
  #last: "Brooks"
  #title: null
  #bio: null
  #phone: null
  #email: "jbrooks@pdi-inc.com.train"
  #inactive: false
  #lastLoginAt: DateTime {#2365 ▶}
  #territory: Territory {#2422 ▶}
  #repTokenId: null
  #createdAt: DateTime {#2366 ▶}
  #updatedAt: DateTime {#2367 ▼
    +"date": "2015-08-21 15:03:07.000000"
    +"timezone_type": 3
    +"timezone": "America/New_York"
  }
  -file: null
}

in SessionRestController.php line 121: 
"79e5ead64a2e1d2ba2ecac1b7dbbabb5fd6ec2b2659fb6bc2ae98d613bfc9aae623fd81dfe2c15ef72f1565ed2f41619baf574387a16a6b1138b2b730c75b21a7081587e9b0494c30b557cdc562a517013d6b78d82bbe4af3e71faaa7257e1caf0aa2342"

in SessionRestController.php line 122: 
"79e5ead64a2e1d2ba2ecac1b7dbbabb5fd6ec2b2659fb6bc2ae98d613bfc9aae623fd81dfe2c15ef72f1565ed2f41619baf574387a16a6b1138b2b730c75b21a7081587e9b0494c30b557cdc562a517013d6b78d82bbe4af3e71faaa7257e1caf0aa2342"

in SessionRestController.php line 125: ▶
Representative {#2369 ▼
  #rep_id: "005800000039cQbAAI"
  #display_name: "Joan Brooks"
  #avatar_url: "https://pdone.s3.amazonaws.com/avatar/default_avatar.png"
  #rep_type: "VEEVA"
  #username: "ertvn52@pdi-inc.com.train"
  #first: "Joan"
  #last: "Brooks"
  #title: null
  #bio: null
  #phone: null
  #email: "jbrooks@pdi-inc.com.train"
  #inactive: false
  #lastLoginAt: DateTime {#2365 ▶}
  #territory: Territory {#2422 ▶}
  #repTokenId: "79e5ead64a2e1d2ba2ecac1b7dbbabb5fd6ec2b2659fb6bc2ae98d613bfc9aae623fd81dfe2c15ef72f1565ed2f41619baf574387a16a6b1138b2b730c75b21a7081587e9b0494c30b557cdc562a517013d6b78d82bbe4af3e71faaa7257e1caf0aa2342"
  #createdAt: DateTime {#2366 ▶}
  #updatedAt: DateTime {#2393 ▼
    +"date": "2015-08-21 15:11:18.000000"
    +"timezone_type": 3
    +"timezone": "America/New_York"
  }
  -file: null
}
```

If I run this query `SELECT repTokenId, updatedAt FROM reps WHERE rep_id='005800000039cQbAAI'` at DB I got this result:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
| repTokenId                                                                                                                                             | updatedAt           |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
| 79e5ead64a2e1d2ba2ecac1b7dbbabb5fd6ec2b2659fb6bc2ae98d613bfc9aae623fd81dfe2c15ef72f1565ed2f41619baf574387a16a6b1138b2b730c75b21a7081587e9b0494c30b557c | 2015-08-21 15:11:18 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
```

Why the entity is returning the wrong values? Why the right `$xsession` value isn't updated? Why `$entRep->getRepTokenId()` is giving me a *unknow* value that doesn't exists in session vars or any other place? What is happening here?

Comment: where do you have your ``$entRep`` from? Did you try to add ``$em->persist($entRep)`` before ``flush``?

Comment: @TomaszMadeyski I've added where `$entRep` comes from, also you should check [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#updating-an-object) you don't need to persist anything when you're updating an existing object

Comment: I know. That's why I asked where did you get your entity from ;)

Comment: but wait. It seems that everything is fine here: First you dump entity (line 114) and ``repTokenId`` is null. Then, after flush all dumps (including line 125) and db result show that ``repTokenId`` is this new value, so what's wrong here?

Comment: @TomaszMadeyski the value on `repTokenId` at `$entRep` obj is not the same as in DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's odd. At beginning your `repTokenId` coming from db is null (dump in line `114`). After persist your entity (dump in line `125`) and db (your `SELECT` sql) has value different than null. Conclusion: Doctrine **is** flushing entity, becase if it didn't you would have `null` in db.

Your new value in db is your token but it got truncated somehow. So I would check two things:

1. Lenght of `repTokenId` field in db. Is it long enough to have such long value?
2. Length of `repTokenId` field in entity definition

Comment: That was the issue, the length of the generated `repTokenId` was `200` and DB column only accept `150` so the rest of the string was truncated, lower that value solve the issue